# How to execute a particular method in java before websphere goes down?

Tags: java, spring, websphere

I have a job in java application which is reading data from Oracle database using spring JDBC after every 5 mins. The java application is running on WebSphere Application Server. It loads records with status 'X', after loading records it changes status of records to 'Y'. We are reading 10k records at a time and supplying 1k records to each thread within 10 threads for certain Processing.
After processing each record, the record state gets changed to 'Z'. Now if something goes wrong while processing records like outOfMemory error and WebSphere goes down, the record state remains 'Y'.
So when next time Server starts, the job starts reading records with status 'X'. But the records which are unprocessed with status 'Y' will never get loaded now. So is there any way to call a method while WebSphere goes down? Within which i can write a piece of code to make the status of unprocessed records to 'X', so that they can get picked next time server starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application has encountered an `OutOfMemoryError` there is really no reliable way for you to make sure that some code gets executed before going down (actually, the `OutOfMemoryError` will not actually make the process die by itself, but it doesn't matter - if you're out of memory you can't be sure that you will be able to do anything at all in that process).

What you should to do is get rid of the 'Y' state. Just make sure that the job that reads the items doesn't get to execute more than once (see below). You should then be able to just read the items, send them off for processing, and just set the state to 'Z' when you're done (preferably in the same transaction as the processing of each item).

Now, you don't specify how your job is kicked off every five minutes, so I'm just assuming you're using Spring's scheduling functionality for that. If this is the case, the job will never get fired more than once *as long as it's still running*. This means that your job needs to keep track of the items it's sent off and wait for them to finish before exiting. This can be done using an [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html). Send each subtask (i.e. chunk of 1k records) to the same `ExecutorCompletionService` and poll for finished tasks as long as there are more tasks left. When all subtasks have returned you can safely exit the parent job.

Another way of doing this (if the 'Y' state is required for some particular reason) would be to check for 'Y' records on startup, e.g. in a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`

Comment: Yes for scheduling i am using **org.springframework.scheduling.quartz** libraries. And the job is getting fired every five minutes cause it never stops. One system is constantly writing data in our DB, so i have to keep it running until server stops. Need to check PostConstruct annotation. Will check and let you know the results.

Comment: Just curious: do the 10 child threads always manage to handle all of the records in the 5 minutes before the new job is fired off? How are the child threads managed? Are you using an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) or do you create new threads on the fly? You should definitely use an `ExecutorService`; continously creating new threads in the system is a sure way of eventually running out of system resources.

Comment: ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);  then submitting the process to threadPool threadPool.submit(myProcess);

Comment: As long as you don't create a new ThreadPoolExecutor instance for each job you should be OK then (creating a new one for each job would be pretty much just as bad as starting the threads yourself). Note that jobs sent to the ThreadPoolExecutor will be queued, so you still risk getting more and more queued items over time.

Comment: Hey thanks for providing logical solution of @PostConstruct. It worked perfectly. +1 for providing alternative.

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged you question with `spring`, you should simply use a singleton bean with a `destroy-method` method : it will be destroyed when the application context is closed and that happens when the application itself is stopped.

XML : `<bean class="..." destroy-method="destroy"/>`

JavaConfig :

```
@Bean(destroy-method = "destroy")
public class ... {
    public void destroy() {
        // do you cleanup
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure in case of OutOfMemory Error application context will be closed properly, so it will hardly give call to destroy-method.

Comment: @DineshM You are right, but I really do not know what can be reasonably expected to work in such case :-(

Comment: One of my friend told me websphere does provide some inbuilt classes, which will help us to do things before it gets down. I am really curious to know does websphere really provide such stuff.